# Open graph action not aproved

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have app and blog which hase facebook based tutorials and news. When I try to make fb social reader app I'm getting this message. Can anyone help me with this?

I have completly diferent desing on my site. I'm using words like facebook,.. in news but i don't have anything other based on fb.

> Your logo and site branding conflicts with Section 5.6 of the Facebook
>   Terms and Section I.8 of the Platform Policy
>   (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/policy_checklist/english/
>   ). Please resubmit with a different graphic that reflects your own
>   branding and the ux of your site. Please make changes below and
>   resubmit for review.

Answer (score 0):

- The instructions you got seem pretty clear.
- We don’t even know your site.

So how *exactly* do you think we can help you here …?

Comment: Site is http://sociallabs.si/ (it's in slovenian langugage). Is there any way to contact facebook which part is in conflict?

Comment: I don’t exactly see what they might not like aout your logo, except maybe FB-like color scheme, but you’re using white text on blue background for your banner next to the logo, font is also facebook-like, etc. Try to avoid having your page look like it’s in any way associated with Facebook.

Comment: There is also problem that if I remove banners and want to re-send an action there is no option to :S

Answer (score 0):

you have to submit Action to Facebook to be approved . goto facebook.com/developers select App then OpenGraph - Action click Submit ...